# How do I save or copy a PDF file's metadata and overwrite another PDF's metadata with it

Tags: windows, pdf

I have two pdf files A and B

I would like to replace file B's metadata with file A's metadata

How can I do this? I want it to be perfectly congruent.

Comment: It is unlikely to be congruent as things like the number of pages will be different. Why do you want to do this anyway? If you really want to do it then read [PDF properties and metadata, Adobe Acrobat](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/pdf-properties-metadata.html) which explains how to edit the metadata.

Comment: See this link [how-to-edit-pdf-metadata-maclinuxwindows/](https://sangonz.wordpress.com/2010/04/11/how-to-edit-pdf-metadata-maclinuxwindows/)